# Unequal height with \tcbincludepdf raster

Tags: tcolorbox, pdfpages, alignment

I combine multiple pdf files into one file, using `tcbraster` and `\tcbincludepdf` (from the package `tcolorbox`). I have a problem with the output. This is the MWE process:

I first use this file `(file name=1.tex)` to generate a single page pdf file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[skins,raster]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\centering
\scalebox{30}{1}\newpage
\end{document}
```

I then use this file `(file name=2.tex)` to generate a 2 page pdf file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[skins,raster]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\centering
\scalebox{30}{2}\newpage
\scalebox{30}{2}\newpage
\end{document}
```

I now use this file `(file name=MWE.tex)`to combine all pdf files using a custom **tcolorbox** raster:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[skins,raster,most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox[
auto counter,
list inside=box,
number format=\arabic,
]{file}[2][]{
enhanced,width=15cm,height=20cm,
breakable,bottom=5mm,
colback=white,
colframe=white,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
coltitle=black,
title=File
\thetcbcounter:\quad#2,#1}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{file}{One Page}
\begin{tcbraster}[%
    raster columns=1,enhanced,
    colframe = white,
   raster equal skip=0pt,
    colback = blue!20!white,width=15cm,height=20cm,
    colbacktitle = black!50,
    fonttitle = \small\ttfamily,
    boxsep = 0pt,
    toptitle = 1mm,
    bottomtitle = 1mm,
    center title,
    graphics pages = {1},
 title = {MWE\ [\imagepage]}]
\tcbincludepdf{1.pdf}
\end{tcbraster}
\end{file}
%
\begin{file}{Two Pages}
\begin{tcbraster}[%
    raster columns=1,enhanced,
    colframe = white,
   raster equal skip=0pt,
    colback = blue!20!white,width=15cm,height=20cm,
    colbacktitle = black!50,
    fonttitle = \small\ttfamily,
    boxsep = 0pt,
    toptitle = 1mm,
    bottomtitle = 1mm,
    center title,
    graphics pages = {1,2},
 title = {MWE\ [\imagepage]}]
\tcbincludepdf{2.pdf}
\end{tcbraster}
\end{file}
\end{document}
```

The problem however, that this code generates difference is heights of the boxes. The second file has one page with a title, and another page without a title. Screenshot:
[image]
I want to be able to flush all boxes to the bottom of the page.

Anyone has an idea how do it?

Comment: There is no difference in `height of the boxes`. The problem is that you insert a title before the first box (with `file` title) and the vertical alignment between pages is different. Unless you use a fixed placement for every page ( with `eso-pic` or similar packages) I don't know how to solve the problem.

Comment: Could you show me how to do it?

Comment: It's the file environment. Why do you need it? btw, if you add `\vspace` after the `\begin{file}` you pull the first box up. you could use the `raster number n` option to try and move the second maybe?

Answer (score 2):

This is a proposal for (at this moment) a partial solution.

From my point of view, the main problem is the use of an external `tcolorbox` called `file` to add a title for the inner `tcbraster`. This external title moves the first box of the inner tcbraster and all other boxes from the same `file` look misplaced. Appart of this title, the `file` environment also uses an internal counter and add information for a `table of boxes`.

What is proposed here is to forget the `file` environment and use a simple `tcbraster` but adding the external title with an `overlay` option for the first box of every raster. The advantage of this solution is that the overlayed title is not considered on the box placement and all boxes look aligned in every page. The main problem is that the counter and table of boxes are lost until more work is done. But as this partial solution is valid only when the `file` title is the only text added around tcbrasters, I need to know if my considerations are valid before trying to do this extra work.

In order to apply an overlay only to the first box a little changes has been applied to original use of `tcbincludepdf`. It seems that options used to apply a particulat style to a certain box into a raster (like `raster number x`) don't work when `tcbincludepdf` is used. Therefore an alternative solution has been used. In this case `tcbincludepdf` has been replaced by a `foreach` construction inside the raster with command `tcbincludegraphics`. The list used in `foreach` corresponds to pages to be included inside the raster.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[skins,raster,most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox[
auto counter,
list inside=box,
number format=\arabic,
]{file}[2][]{
enhanced,width=15cm,height=20cm,
breakable,bottom=5mm,
colback=white,
colframe=white,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
coltitle=black,
title=File
\thetcbcounter:\quad#2,#1}

\tcbset{%
myrasterstyle/.style={%
    enhanced,
    raster columns=1,
   raster equal skip=0pt,
    colframe = white,
   colback = blue!20!white, width=15cm,height=20cm,
   colbacktitle = black!50,
   fonttitle = \small\ttfamily,
   boxsep = 0pt,
   toptitle = 1mm,
   bottomtitle = 1mm,
   center title,
%   graphics pages = {1},
    title = {MWE\ [\imagepage]},
    raster number 1/.style={overlay={\node[anchor=south west, font=\bfseries] at (frame.north west) {File: #1};}}
}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcbraster}[myrasterstyle={One Page}]
\foreach \i in {1}{
\tcbincludegraphics[graphics options={page=\i}]{1.pdf}}
\end{tcbraster}

\begin{tcbraster}[myrasterstyle={Two Pages}]
\foreach \i in {1,2}{
\tcbincludegraphics[graphics options={page=\i}]{2.pdf}}
\end{tcbraster}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Update: tcbraster replaced by a foreach loop*

This is a second alternative which I hope solve all problems. This solution consists in using a `foreach` loop to build independent `tcolorboxes` instead of using a `tcbraster`.
Every box is formed by an external box (for the title) and an inner `tcbincludepdf` box with the desired style. But two kind of external boxes are used, one with initialization options (to build a table of contents and enumerate all files) which prints the title and a second one whiout initizlization options and with a `\phantom` title. This way box boxes will have the same space and inner boxes will be aligned on each page.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
%\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[skins,raster,most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox[
    auto counter,
    list inside=box,
    number format=\arabic,
    ]{file}[2][]{%
    enhanced,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    coltitle=black,
    title=File \thetcbcounter:\quad#2,
    blanker,
    #1
}

\newtcolorbox{auxfile}[2][]{%
    enhanced,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    coltitle=black,
    title=\phantom{File \thetcbcounter:\quad#2},
    blanker,
    #1
}

\tcbset{
    innerfile/.style={
        colframe=white,
        colback=blue!20,
        width=15cm,
        height=20cm,
        colbacktitle=black!50,
        fonttitle=\small\ttfamily,
        boxsep = 0pt,
        toptitle = 1mm,
        bottomtitle = 1mm,
        center title,
        title = {MWE\ [\imagepage]},
        graphics pages = {#1}
    }
}

\begin{document}

%\tcblistof{box}{List of boxes}

\begin{file}{One Page}
\tcbincludepdf[innerfile={1}]{1.pdf}
\end{file}

\foreach \i [count=\ni] in {1,3,6,7,...,9,12}{
    \ifnum\ni<2
        \begin{file}{Some Pages}        
        \tcbincludepdf[innerfile={\i}]{2.pdf}
        \end{file}
    \else
        \begin{auxfile}{Some Pages}
        \tcbincludepdf[innerfile={\i}]{2.pdf}
        \end{auxfile}
    \fi
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes. This is a valid solution. There are only a couple of things to pay attention to. Please note that with the previous setup: 

(1) I was able to assign certain pages to include (for instance: {1-3,6-9,12} etc.)

(2) I was able to add a TOC using:

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Files}
\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\textbf{page}\par}
\tcblistof[]{box}{}

Comment: @MorZahavi Something like `{1-3,6-9,12}` could be defined into a `foreach` command with `{1,2,3,6,7,9,12}`. For longer ranges you could do `{1,2,...,5,6,...10,15,20}`. The difference between the values before `...` define the step to follow. You can find more information in `TikZ` documentation.

Comment: @MorZahavi I've tried to find a solution for the listofboxes but I couldn't. The use of an external `tcolorbox` is valid, but the height of the title makes the first page go lower than following pages. If you can find how tall is the title box you could apply this shift to following boxes. Another solution could be to apply `detach title` in your external tcolorbox and later on use it as `overlay` like in my proposed solution. but I could find how to save the title and reuse into another tcolorbox. Maybe you can write some new questions with this particular problems.

Comment: @MorZahavi I've proposed a second solution. I hope it's better.

Comment: Great. It works. Could you please tell me how can I center the files to page center (in case I scale them, or use geometry)?